# How to create layout for Android Youtube App List Item

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create Android layout of type list item in Android Youtube App.
I need to display an Image in a ImageView and display some TextViews to the right side of ImageView Vertically. How can I create a layout for this type of UI design.

Can anyone provide me sample layout for the above mentioned scenario ?

Thanks in Advance,